# How do curly brackets in Spring Security Ldap Authentication Filter work?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

While I was doing research to implement LDAP Authentication using Spring Security, I saw that Group Search and User Search filters were usually implementing with {0}s. Such as:

```
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
        .contextSource()
          .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
          .and()
        .passwordCompare()
          .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
          .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
  }
```

[In a site](https://documentation.progress.com/output/oe116sp/index.html#page/new%2Fbasic-ldap-configuration.html%23), I have seen that that was a token used to say "equal". However, it was not extremely clear, and I couldn't find information on the formal documentation about this.

What are those curly brackets really standing out for and can they have any other values rather than 0?

Answer (score 0):

I have found such an info [online](https://www.sourceallies.com/2009/10/spring-ldap-group-authorization-tip/): The value between the curly brackets is a placeholder and it can be 0 or 1.

`{0}` contains the username with the entire ldap base and,

`{1}` only contains username.